# in parceljs how to make it pick the min file in node modules

Tags: node-modules, parceljs

I am using 'animate.css' as a npm package. to use it I specify `import 'animate.css'` during development. But in production it says to include 'animate.min.css'. How to specify to parceljs to pick the animate.min.css during production build.

or would `import animate.css` would be able to resolve to right `animate.css` in development build and `animate.min.css` in production build. how does the resolver know to pick right file as the main file is specified as animate.css in the package.json
But the there is "Files" property in package.json ...not sure if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

The high-level answer is that parcel [automatically minifies and optimizes css files](https://parceljs.org/features/production/#minification), so you don't need to do anything special to make sure that your production build is as small as possible.

If you want to understand in detail how parcel handles this particular package, read on.

Parcel generally follows node resolution conventions to figure out which files to actually import when you reference a package name.

In this case, the `import "animate.css"` will tell parcel to go looking in the nearest `node_modules` folder for a for a subfolder called `animate.css`. It finds it, and then looks for the `package.json` file at the root. In this case, [the `package.json` has a `main` field that points to a file called `animate.css`](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css/blob/847fdd268a6d36b7662ee43febe2a1bab30547b0/package.json#L4) (e.g. the un-minified version).

Parcel will use that file as the basis for development and production builds. When you run parcel in development, it leaves this file untouched. When you run `parcel build` it will process this (unminified) file through `cssnano` so the build output is minified.

So the interesting fact is that even though there is another file called `node_modules/animate/animate.min.css` living there, Parcel is able to achieve the desired behavior without touching it. The publishers of `animate.css` included it for other folks that aren't using a bundler that's as awesome as parcel - you can safely ignore it.